# multiple mdl-sheet overlapping issue

Tags: jquery, html, css, material-design-lite

Hi quick question I am wondering if you can have multiple mdl-sheets on one page? they all need to get the same form however.

My attempt has left it over lapping each other instead of next to eachother left to right.

https://codepen.io/russellharrower/pen/RZVmwo 
Error is in CSS i know

css

```
/* Downloaded from https://www.codeseek.co/ */
body {
  background: #ECEFF1;
}

.mdl-layout__content {
  padding: 24px 12px;
}
.mdl-layout__content h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 .3em;
}

.mdl-sheet__container {
  right: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
          transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.mdl-sheet {
  position: relative;
  background: #FF5722;
  float:left;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 180ms;
  transition: all 180ms;
}
.mdl-sheet .mdl-sheet__content {
  display: none;
}

.mdl-sheet__icon {
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12px, -12px);
          transform: translate(-12px, -12px);
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.mdl-sheet--opened {
  background: #fff;
  color: #263238;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}
.mdl-sheet--opened .mdl-sheet__icon {
  display: none;
}
.mdl-sheet--opened .mdl-sheet__content {
  display: block;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sheets were overlapping because of you have inserted another mdl-sheet into previous one. In css I have added `display:inline-block` to show them next to each other left to right.

```js
var $sheet = $('.mdl-sheet');

if ($sheet.length > 0) {
  $('html').on('click', function() {
    $sheet.removeClass('mdl-sheet--opened')
  });

  $sheet.on('click', function(event) {
    event.stopPropagation();

    $sheet.addClass('mdl-sheet--opened');
  });
}
```

```css
/* Downloaded from https://www.codeseek.co/ */

body {
  background: #ECEFF1;
}

.mdl-layout__content {
  padding: 24px 12px;
}

.mdl-layout__content h1 {
  font-size: 30px;
  margin: 0 0 .3em;
}

.mdl-sheet__container {
  right: 32px;
  bottom: 32px;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
}

.mdl-sheet {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  background: #FF5722;
  float: none;
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 180ms;
  transition: all 180ms;
}

.mdl-sheet .mdl-sheet__content {
  display: none;
}

.mdl-sheet__icon {
  color: #fff;
  position: static;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-12px, -12px);
  transform: translate(-12px, -12px);
  font-size: 24px;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.mdl-sheet--opened {
  background: #fff;
  color: #263238;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 240px;
  height: auto;
  min-height: 150px;
  max-height: 80vh;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.mdl-sheet--opened .mdl-sheet__icon {
  display: none;
}

.mdl-sheet--opened .mdl-sheet__content {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script>
<div class="mdl-sheet__container">
  <div class="mdl-sheet mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-sheet__icon">add</i>
    <div class="mdl-sheet__content">
      <div class="mdl-list">
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Bryan Cranston</span>
          </span>
          <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Aaron Paul</span>
          </span>
          <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Bob Odenkirk</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
              <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-sheet mdl-shadow--2dp">
    <i class="material-icons mdl-sheet__icon">add</i>
    <div class="mdl-sheet__content">
      <div class="mdl-list">
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Bryan Cranston</span>
          </span>
          <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Aaron Paul</span>
          </span>
          <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="mdl-list__item">
          <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
              <i class="material-icons mdl-list__item-avatar">person</i>
              <span>Bob Odenkirk</span>
          </span>
          <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
              <a class="mdl-list__item-secondary-action" href="#"><i class="material-icons">star</i></a>
            </span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```